# TinyMCE - How to see javascript code behind some actions?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I found that tinyMCE is free and open source

If I click, for example, on the icon B - bold, and some text becomes bold, is there a way to see javascript code that stands behind that action ?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

Comment: @KooiInc - I already tried, but can't find the corresponding file with click functions. So I hope the browser can identify it somehow

Comment: It's a complex beast. Maybe https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/dom/DOMUtils.ts#L242 is a good starting point?

Comment: Or inform yourself more generally: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/05/building-wysiwyg-editor-javascript-slatejs/

Comment: @KooiInc - on your github link I tried `Ctrl F` - `bold`. There is nothing - just one single comment line. Makes me crazy Thanks for the smash link

Comment: In earlier days I would have pointed you to [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), but it's deprecated. Maybe the links in the MDN-document bring you further.

Comment: @KooiInc - about `execCommand` -  yes, deprecated - but I saw this warning 10 year ago - and they are still working without a problem in any browser.